# iOS Swift how to order Dictionnary by keys

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to order a Dictionary of [Double : Article] by key (The Double).

I've tried everything, now I have the following code :

```
    // getting an array of sorted keys
    let articlesKeys = articles.keys.sort{$0 > $1}

    var sortedArticles = [Double:Article]()

    // trying to fill the new dictionary in a descending keys order
    for key in articlesKeys
    {
        sortedArticles[key] = articles[key]
    }

    // replacing the old dictionary (articles)
    // with the new and ordered one (sortedArticles)
    articles.removeAll()
    articles = sortedArticles
```

The problem is that "articleKeys" is ordered

print(articleKeys) ===> [220, 218, 110]

but when i print out "sortedArticles" or the new "articles" :

print(sortedArticles) ===> [110 : X], [220 : Y], [218 : Z]

The dictionary has not been ordered :(

Comment: If articleKeys is ordered, have you tried to user reverse() function? articlesKeys = articlesKeys.reverse()
print(articlesKeys)

Comment: A dictionary is an unordered collection, it can not be ordered like the way you would like to.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but we can use ordered array that contains dictionary keys, and get key value from it, then object by key from dictionary..

Comment: Thank's @AlexKosyakov, i'll do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered - it's their nature. You just can't sort them. But you can somehow use arrays to store the key and value as its values.

Read more about them here http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary

there is actually something that will help you there. read more about keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the keys array you can directly do this in the sort method of the dictionary.

For example -

```
let dict = [1.0:"One",  3.0:"Three", 2.0:"Two"]
let sortedDict = dict.sort { $0.0 > $1.0 }
print(sortedDict)
// OUTPUT : [(3.0, "Three"), (2.0, "Two"), (1.0, "One")]
```

Here you are sorting the dict and assigning it to the sortedDict.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

or in a loop

```
let dict = [1.0:"One",  3.0:"Three", 2.0:"Two"]

for (Key, Value) in dict.sort(<) {
  print("Key = \(Key), Wert =  \(Value)")
}

//Output
Key = 1.0, Wert =  One
Key = 2.0, Wert =  Two
Key = 3.0, Wert =  Three
```